# NodeJS not finding assets

Tags: node.js, assets

I'm trying to get my node application running on my server again after it crashed initially. I got the files up and the app running but all the assets are not being found. In my console. it's showing these errors (and more)

```
GET http://mvmdesign.org:8080/css/style.css  mvmdesign.org/:1
GET http://mvmdesign.org:8080/css/colorpicker.css  mvmdesign.org/:1
```

From what I see it looks like it's not finding the public folder. Here's my app.configure which I haven't touched since it last worked

```
app.configure ->
  @.set "port", process.env.PORT or 8080
  @.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
  @.set "view engine", "jade"
  @.use express.favicon()
  @.use express.logger("dev")
  @.use express.bodyParser()
  @.use express.methodOverride()
  @.use app.router
  @.use require("connect-assets")()
  @.use require("stylus").middleware(
    src: __dirname + "/public"
    compress: true
  )
  @.use express.static path.join(__dirname, "public")
```

Don't think it should make a difference, but these files are in a subdomain folder for mvmdesign.org, and when I console.d __dirname, it showed the correct path, so I'm clueless as to what's going on.

I'll try to keep it running on mvmdesign.org:8080 now if that helps

Comment: Try moving your static handler to the top (at least before the app.router line!) Also, I don't think they should be inside configure, most apps that I've seen set this up before the definition of configure.

Comment: I'll try that out, but It's how express has it setup by default